# Java swing with synth checkboxes/radio button borders disappear after long uptime

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, radio-button, synth

I have a GUI app that is supposed to run continuously, if the user wishes, showing the state of some database operations.

It uses checkboxes in a column in a JTable, as well as stand alone checkboxes.  After a couple days of up-time the box in the checkbox refuses to render, though the text is still visible.  This occurs for checkboxes active on the screen as well as those that are in new windows, instantiated after the problem is noticed.  A similar situation is observed for radio buttons.  The users can still interact with the components.

The GUI can use quite a bit of memory, but the logs (from log4j) do not indicate any problems.

It sound, to me, like a bug in swing or synth.

---

Now you see them.  Now you don't.
[image: Available]
[image: Disappeared]

[image: Radios are there]
[image: Not there]

---

I have not been able to find any documentation of a bug in swing or synth.  Has anybody else observed this problem?  Is there a resolution?

Comment: Verify that Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I assume you are using proper Layout except `null` layout.

Comment: @trashgod:  Could this be related to a potential EDT issue, when new components, constructed in a new frame/window, exhibit the problem once the problem is encountered elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, among myriad other possible causes; an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem may shed light.